# Xcode won't run instance?

Tags: xcode

So I just started learning how to use Xcode as a school project and every time I run the app I am building it will show up in the emulator nice and everything, but if I try to change it a little and re-run it I get this : An instance of “Calculator” is already running. Choose “Stop” to terminate and launch a new instance.   When I do click stop it just does nothing. Is there anyway to fix this so I don't have to force quite Xcode every time I want to run my project?

Comment: Is the Stop button grayed out?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: Can you long-press it and then close every process that shows up?